# Android Twitter SDK showing blank screen

Tags: android, twitter, android-twitter

When I implemented the Twitter SDK (Fabric), I was unable to [compose tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/compose).
The screen turns black / white and a toast displays:

> shell has been granted Superuser permissions

After that, it resumes the referrer intent, doesn't log anything. I've double checked the manual, cleaned the project, etc., but nothing helped.

Code:

```
Fabric.with(AdActivity.this, new TweetComposer());
TweetComposer.Builder tweet = new TweetComposer.Builder(AdActivity.this)
    .text("text"))
    .image(imageUri);
tweet.show();
```

What could be the problem?